# Javascript URL base on local/prod

Tags: javascript

I want to refer to the domain base in Javascript, which would be `http://localhost/project` in my local environment and http://www.project.com (or https depending on the page). I'm currently defining 2 global variables, one for links to other non-https pages (where I don't want to use the fact that the current page may be https) and one that picks up whether the page is https or not, to load resources without having an unsecure elements warning.

Local version:

```
var link_base_url = 'http://localhost/project/'; //for links to other non-secure pages
if(window.location.protocol == 'https:') var base_url = 'http://localhost/project/'; //SSL version for displaying resources or calling ajax scripts
else var base_url = 'http://localhost/project/'; //non-SSL version for displaying resources or calling ajax scripts
```

Prod version:

```
var link_base_url = 'http://www.project.com/'; //for links to other non-secure pages
if(window.location.protocol == 'https:') var base_url = 'https://www.project.com/'; //SSL version for displaying resources or calling ajax scripts
else var base_url = 'http://www.project.com/'; //non-SSL version for displaying resources or calling ajax scripts
```

I am no expert on Javascript but I think this is probably not the cleanest way to do it: it forces me to change these few lines of code each time I want to deploy this script, and from what I understand using global variables is not that good.

Is there a better way to do this? I am not using any JS framework like Ember.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: There is no point in doing this. The URL '/' would refer to your host URL irrespective of the machine serving your content. What is it that you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: If I type "/ajax/controller" it would only work if we are in the same root: as some views may be called from subfolders e.g "/admin/users/view" I cannot use a relative path easily, as some functions are common throughout the application and using relative paths would not work very well. Therefore I want to use the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use location.href, which contains the entire URL of the current page, to check your current environment (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp).

```
var checkURL = location.href, base_url = '', link_base_url = '';

if (/\/\/localhost\/project\//.test(checkURL)) {
    link_base_url = 'http://localhost/project/';
    if (window.location.protocol == 'https:') {
        base_url = 'https://localhost/project/';
    } else {
        base_url = 'http://localhost/project/';
    }
} else {
    link_base_url = 'http://www.project.com/';
    if (window.location.protocol == 'https:') {
        base_url = 'https://www.project.com/';
    } else {
        base_url = 'http://www.project.com/';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I simplified it to `if (/localhost/.test(location.href))` but that solves my question

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
var link_base_url = 'http://'+window.location.host+'/';
var base_url = /\.com$/.test(window.location.hostname) ? window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/' : link_base_url;
```

Comment: Edit: it actually doesn't solve my issue as my root URL on local is localhost/project, while it's directly project.com on prod. Using the location host does't take the /project/ folder in local.

Comment: I forgot about that, my mistake.